# How to solve the errors when I run SPADE

Tags: perl, parsing, nlp, charniak-parser

I run the [`SPADE`](http://www.isi.edu/licensed-sw/spade/) package and I referenced the Charniak Parser according to the documentation and edited `spade.pl` for the `$CHP` variable, but it did not work. It still throws an exception as follows

```
sh: 1: /home/khaing/Downloads/CharniakParser/parseIt: not found
system /home/khaing/Downloads/CharniakParser/parseIt -LEn /home/khaing/Downloads/CharniakParser/DATA/ /home/khaing/Documents/test.txt > /home/khaing/Documents/test.txt.chp failed: 32512 at /home/khaing/Downloads/SPADE/bin/spade.pl line 38.
```

The exception is that `parseIt` is not found. When I review the Charniak Parser, it has five folders: `CVS`, `ecstuff`, `DATA`, `TRAIN` and `PARSE`. I did not see `parseIt`. But I found `pareIt.c` in `PARSE` folder so I edited the path CharniakParser/PARSE/parseIt but it still has errors.

Comment: Please give a link to the page where you downloaded the parser. I cannot see it on Charniak's home page

Comment: Please see [*Compiling Charniak's Parser*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7287087)

Comment: The version of the parser on Charniak's website doesn't compile easily these days. The currently maintained version is at https://github.com/BLLIP/bllip-parser. To build parseIt, you'll need to run `make PARSE` from the top-level directory.

Comment: >> here is link for parser [link] (ftp://ftp.cs.brown.edu/pub/nlparser/) @ Borodin

Answer (score 1):

The instructions that you link to say

> Edit spade.pl in the bin/ directory; set the value for the $CHP variable to the directory path for Charniak's parser

So if SPADE cannot find `parseIt` then you have set `$CHP` to the wrong path.

If there is no `parseIt` binary but you have `parseIt.c` then I would guess that you have to build it. Check the documentation for the *Charniak Parser*

Comment: in SPADE, the instruction is " set the value for the $CHP variable to the directory path for Charniak parser" . So, i set the value ' $CHP = "/home/Khaing/CharniakParser/";' for path of the parser.  But in line 26, the code is  '@args = ("$CHP/parseIt -LEn $CHP/DATA/ $argv > $argv.chp");
 print STDERR "Charniak's syntactic parser in progress...\n";' In running, the error appeared like that " /home/Khaing/CharniakParser/parseIt not found" . I didn't find any information on parseIt. May i know if i need to create parseIt under this parser or not. Please! @Borodin

Answer (score 0):

Here are concrete steps to obtain the latest version of the Charniak parser and build it:

1. Make a directory where you'll install the parser: (where `/path/to` is the directory you'd like to put the parser in -- maybe `/home/Khaing` in your case)

   ```
   shell% mkdir /path/to/bllip-parser
   shell% cd /path/to/bllip-parser/
   ```
2. Download and extract the latest version of the Charniak Parser:

   ```
   shell% wget https://github.com/BLLIP/bllip-parser/archive/master.zip
   shell% unzip master.zip
   shell% mv bllip-parser-master/* bllip-parser-master/.* .
   shell% rmdir bllip-parser-master
   ```
3. Build the parser:

   ```
   shell% make PARSE
   ```
4. Confirm that `parseIt` was built correctly:

   ```
   shell% ls first-stage/PARSE/parseIt  
   first-stage/PARSE/parseIt
   ```

   If you run `first-stage/PARSE/parseIt` you should see its help menu.
5. At this point, you can set `$CHP` to point inside the `bllip-parser` directory you made in step 1: Change `$CHP` in `spade.pl` to `/path/to/bllip-parser/first-stage/PARSE/`

Comment: Thanks a lot @dmcc, i did step by step to your instructions. In step 3, when i did " make PARSE", i found 2 errors . How can I fix them? i searched the errors frequently but still appear. **** ' khaing@khaing-VirtualBox:~/bllip-parser$ make PARSE <br>make -C first-stage/PARSE parseIt <br> make[1]: Entering directory `/home/khaing/bllip-parser/first-stage/PARSE' <br>g++ -MMD -O3 -Wall -ffast-math -finline-functions -fomit-frame-pointer -fstrict-aliasing  -c Bchart.C<br> make[1]: g++: Command not found <br>make[1]: *** [Bchart.o] Error 127 ' ***

Comment: Looks like you don't have g++ which you'll need to compile the C++ code. You should install gcc (which includes g++).